# Mic records sound twice as fast

Tags: audio, alsa, recording, microphone

I've a webcam with a built-in microphone. When I record sound with eg. `arecord`, it says I've recorded eg. 6 seconds of sound, but when I try to play it with eg. `aplay`, it says I've only recorded 3 seconds and it plays the sound twice as fast. This happens with every recording and playing program. How can I make it record sound at normal speed?

Comment: Very likely some rate mismatch. There's not enough info to determine what exactly happens. Try setting a rate, e.g. `arecord -r 16000` for double the default rate, or `arecord -r 44100` resp. `arecord -r 48000` for rates more likely to work. It may also be that recording is ok, but playback has a mismatch, so try the same with `aplay`.

Comment: @dirkt: That doesn't change anything: https://i.imgur.com/DkHpSI5.png

Comment: Please provide the output of `arecord -l` and `aplay -l`, and the contents of `~/.asoundrc` (if you have one). I assume you don't use Pulseaudio? And of course it will also happen in Audacity and Firefox, they use the same API.

Comment: @dirkt: [Here](http://pastebin.com/raw/EebBBuvC) is the output of both `aplay -l` and `arecord -l`, I don't have a `.asoundrc` and I'm not using PulseAudio…

Comment: Definitely the Namtai, as it happens [elsewhere](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=37443). May need quirk handling in the driver if the rates are wrong. Verify the driver is `snd-usb-audio` (look at output of `dmesg` after plugging in camera). Upgrade to newest kernel. If the problem doesn't go away, file a bug for the [ALSA kernel drivers](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/buglist.cgi?component=Sound%28ALSA%29&product=Drivers).

Comment: @dirkt: The driver is indeed `snd-usb-audio`, btw I already have the newest kernel, so the only thing I could do is to file a bug for the ALSA kernel drivers?